# In Gstreamer pipeline Camera distortion correction, from C++ API, I could not able parse camera parameters and not corrected image.?

Tags: c++, camera, gstreamer

In Gstreamer pipeline Camera distortion correction, From terminal I am able to get distortion corrected image. But from C++ API, I could not able parse camera parameters and not getting corrected image.
from terminal:
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=calibration3.jpg ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! cameraundistort settings="$DATA" ! cameracalibrate ! jpegenc ! filesink location=calib_output.jpg

DATA = is xml data which has camera matrix, distortion coefficients...

From C++ API, I am not able to do... Please share your ideas....
I have tried different way, Argument parsing, declare parameters (DATA) as cost * char... not taking these parameters... not corrected...

Please share your ideas....,   Thanks in advance

Ideas or piece of C++ code on cameraundistort plugin...